# JWT - Invalid Signature when trying to decode token generated by java Jwts with jwt.io online tool

Tags: java, jwt

Here's my Java code, which is generating tokens:

private static final GzipCompressionCodec COMPRESSION_CODEC = new GzipCompressionCodec();

```
 private String issuer;
 private int expirationSec;
 private int clockSkewSec;
 private String secretKey;

//constructor, some other methods

 public String createToken(final Map<String, String> attributes) {
        Date now = new Date();
        Date exp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * expirationSec));

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims();
        claims.putAll(attributes);

        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuer(issuer)
                .signWith(HS256, secretKey)
                .compressWith(COMPRESSION_CODEC)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(exp)
                .compact();
  }
```

I can decode this token in Java without any problems, but when I try to decode it with https://jwt.io I get "Invalid Signature" error. I need to extract token expiration date. I've also tried to generate token without compression, but also fails.

Comment: Invalid signature is shown because the signing keys are different. Even if they are different, you can still see the decoded token on the right side. the iat gives you the issued at date. You can use that to evaluate the expiration time

Comment: past your secret into the field in the right column on jwt.io under VERIFY SIGNATURE and the paste the token to the left column. Without knowing the secret, no tool can verify a signature

Comment: Thank you, I've added exp to header, so now it's visible without secret.